# How to avoid specific #ifdef in multi - platform qt code?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, multiplatform

I have a QT input listener class, that signals `stdin` inputs in a running `QCoreApplication`. I want to use that on both windows and linux.

My current approach is to use `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` inside both header and cpp to execute the platform-specific code. As I know, that `#ifdef` is considered harmful and should be avoided, I want to refactor this in a manner where I have one single header file `inputlistener.h` and let the build system choose between a specific `windows/inputlistener.cpp` or `linux/inputlistener.cpp`, maybe with an additional `inputlistener_global.cpp` that holds the code, which is not platform specific.

However, I can't find a solution, how to get the `#ifdef` in the header out of the way.

How can I achieve that?

Here is my current approach:

```
#inputlistener.h

#ifndef INPUTLISTENER_H
#define INPUTLISTENER_H

#include <QtCore>

class inputlistener : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    QWinEventNotifier* m_notifier;
#else
    QSocketNotifier* m_notifier;
#endif

signals:

    void inputeventhappened(int keycode);

private slots:

    void readyRead();

public:
    inputlistener();
};

#endif // INPUTLISTENER_H

#inputlistener.cpp

#include "inputlistener.h"
#include "curses.h"

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <windows.h>
#endif

inputlistener::inputlistener()
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    m_notifier = new QWinEventNotifier(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
    connect(m_notifier, &QWinEventNotifier::activated
#else
    m_notifier = new QSocketNotifier(0, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
    connect(m_notifier, &QSocketNotifier::activated
#endif
        ,
        this, &inputlistener::readyRead);

    readyRead(); // data might be already available without notification
}

void inputlistener::readyRead()
{
    // It's OK to call this with no data available to be read.
    int c;
    while ((c = getch()) != ERR) {
        emit inputeventhappened(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not true that "`#ifdef` is harmful". It's a matter of taste and depends on the particular application and situation. I wouldn't worry about this unless it's causing a real problem. You're gonna blow up your code in size just for some dogma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create separate `EventListener.cpp` files for `windows` and `unix` and put these files into subdirectories like (`win`, `linux`). To the makefile or to the projectfile you can add one implementation file based on the current platform. The compiler will compile just one file for the current platform.

With this method you can avoid `ifdef`ing totally.

If the definitions are different you can use `pImpl` idiom to separate the implementation details of a class: https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html

Comment: That'd be just moving "ifdefs" up the chain into the project file. Not that it's somehow worse or better.

Comment: I wanted to separate the implementations. Im aware that this is a valid approach. But I am concerned about the header because the definitions are different, too, not only the implementations.

Comment: If the definitions are different you can use `pImpl` idiom to separate the implementation details of a class: https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html

Comment: @devjb: I've put this extension into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `WinEventListener` and `UnixEventListener` (or something else) each using it's own implementation (instead of trying to fit it into one via ifdefs), each implementing common `Listener` interface (and residing in separate files).

Then, have a factory function that'd return listener appropriate to OS. That they there would be only one single place that might require ifdefs.

But in general, `ifdef`ing something might be the best or the only course of action (e.g. when you already abstracting something). Conditional compilation is one of the few valid/justified usages of preprocessor (it's what it was made for).

Also, in your particular case, be sure there is not already appropriate code/class in Qt lib. For most common stuff chances are there is already existing abstraction (or recommended ways to do that).